Possible to expand/use a variable value, in another variable, in a systemd service file?
All I want to do, is to re-use the name I enter in the User= specification in a systemd .service file; e.g. I would have liked to do this in a .service file:
# ...
User=my-username
Environment="MYPATH=/tmp/${User}"
# ...
ExecStart=/path/to/myprogram --mypath=${MYPATH}

... unfortunately, it seems that you cannot - so I am forced to enter the name verbatim multiple times to get something to work:
# ...
User=my-username
#Environment="MYPATH=/tmp/${User}" # cannot use variable in a variable; write directly in ExecStart
# User= is not accessible as variable either, so define USER environment variable, and enter AGAIN "my-username" verbatim
Environment="USER=my-username"
# ...
ExecStart=/path/to/myprogram --mypath=/tmp/${USER}

I mean, ... what a mess; I cannot even believe there are no types of  variables (don't have to be "environment" ones) that can be used in .service files units/section, but ... eh:

https://serverfault.com/q/794922/how-to-use-the-home-environment-variable-in-systemd-service-files


The full list of supported variables (called "Specifiers") is here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers.
There is no specifier for the home directory of user the service is run as (the one specified by User=). There is only one for the user running the service manager. ...

%h is the home directory of the user running the service manager instance. In case of the system manager this resolves to "/root".



https://serverfault.com/questions/868373/how-to-use-variables-in-a-systemd-service-file


These are environment variables. They are not used in sections, but passed to the processes. In this particular case they are referenced in the command line of ExecStart(Pre|Post)?.
The Environment directive is only for creating variables in the environment of the called process, not variables in the service file itself?
How does "Sets environment variables for executed processes." not already cover this?


setting environment variables from command line inside unit files


Commands in ExecStart= in systemd service units do not really run on a shell, so shell expansions (such as the command substitution $(...) you use there) are not really available.
You can use them by calling a shell script explicitly, with /bin/sh -c '...', in your ExecStartPre=.
Note that you need to escape the $ itself, by using $$, otherwise systemd will try to interpret as a systemd variable expansion.
Please note that using systemctl set-environment like you're doing is really not recommended, since you're creating a global environment variable ${date} that will be available everywhere.
Instead, consider running your ExecStart= command through a shell, in which case you can define a shell variable ${date} and just use it in the single place you need it:
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'date=$$(/bin/date ...


So I would have hoped, at least to be able to do something like:
# ...
User=my-username
#Environment="MYPATH=/tmp/${User}" # cannot use variable in a variable; write directly in ExecStart
# User= is not accessible as variable either, so define USER environment variable, and enter AGAIN "my-username" verbatim
Environment="USER=my-username"
# ...
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'export MYPATH=/tmp/${USER}'
ExecStart=/path/to/myprogram --mypath=${MYPATH}

... but apparently ExecStartPre runs in its own process/"subshell", and after it exist, MYPATH is unset too - and it seems it even does not expand ${USER}, since service status would print the unexpanded variable:
  Process: 7165 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c export MYPATH=/tmp/${USER} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

So, as I find it somewhat unbelievable I cannot really use variables (or specifiers) in this way - can anyone more acquainted with systemd just confirm, if the kind of variable expansion I wanted to do in a .service file units/sections (other than ExecStart), is possible or not - without wrapping the ExecStart= call in a sh -c wrapper (or setting systemctl globals)?
